# Value of complete.cases in each file inside a folder as a table with columns [id],[complete.cases value]

Tags: r, function

A folder has dozens of csv files. Each csv file is named with just an id ranging from 1 - 332. Each file contains two columns "sulfate" and "nitrate" with numeric values of pollution level. I want to create a table that lists ids (file names as 'id') in one column, and number of complete cases (as 'nobs') in that file in another column.

Please suggest modification to the code below (or something totally new is fine)

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  csvfiles <- dir(directory, "*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
  data <- lapply(csvfiles[id], read.csv)
  for (filedata in data) {
  d <- filedata[["sulfate"]]
  d <- d[complete.cases(d)] # remove NA values
  d1 <- filedata[["nitrate"]]
  d1<- d1[complete.cases(d1)]
  }
  paste(id, (length(d)+length(d1)))
}
```

Currently the above code just binds the id numbers with the total of complete cases across all the files in that id-range.

Answer (score 0):

some suggested modifications:
you can read in and process the csv file within the same function. Use `cbind` to add the 2 columns that you require. Then row bind all the data.frames into 1 data.frame

```
complete <- function(directory, id = 1:332) {
  lsData <- lapply(id, function(n) {
    df <- read.csv(paste0(directory, "/", n, ".csv"))
    cbind(id=n, df, nobs=nrow(df[complete.cases(df),,drop=FALSE]))
  })
  do.call(rbind, lsData)
}
```

Comment: When I tried running the code above on a Mac using R-studio, it gave the following error:                                                                            > complete("sample", 25:27)
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'sample\25.csv': No such file or directory                                    And, I have checked the path of the working directory..the directory "sample" is very much there. Any clue what's wrong with the code?

Comment: does the sample folder contain the file 25.csv?

Comment: Yes. The working directory contains the "sample" folder, and the "sample" folder contains all the csv files including "25.csv"

Comment: what does `file.exists(normalizePath("sample\\25.csv"))` return?

Comment: it returns [1] FALSE . But when I run list.files() I see the folder "sample" . And, when I do list.files("sample") I see all those csv files including 25.csv . Even if I change it to complete("sample", 120) it returns same error . The files are definitely there.

Comment: What about list.files(paste0(getwd(),"\\sample")) ?

Comment: returns    character(0)  but again list.files("sample") returns the names of all the 332 csv files.

Comment: R u sure u are in the correct working directory in R?

Comment: Yes. I too had that doubt...so I checked my drive...and found the files there. The code I used earlier (posted at the beginning of this thread) does not return any error messages which means those files are being read from the same WD. Also, why else would list.files() return "sample" - the folder. And, list.files("sample") return the names of all the csv files?! list.files by default looks in the WD. [Now, I am puzzled]

Comment: i am as puzzled as you because `list.files(paste0(getwd(),"\\sample"))` returns `character(0)` and `file.exists(normalizePath("sample\\25.csv"))` returns `FALSE`. what does this `normalizePath("sample")==normalizePath(paste0(getwd(),"\\sample"))` return? you might want to print this out `dir("sample", "*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)`

Comment: dir("sample", "*\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)   returns the names of all the csv files (incl. 25.csv)

Comment: can you copy and paste the full path for 25.csv here from the `dir` output

Comment: normalizePath("sample")==normalizePath(paste0(getwd(),"\\sam‌​ple"))  returns FALSE with the error msg "No such file or directory" BUT when i change the back slashes (\\) before sample to forward slashes (//) it returns TRUE! May be on a Mac the slashes are reversed ?!

Comment: After changing the back slashes to forward slashes I get the same msg. Had tried this earlier though. Pls see below:

Comment: Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, "rt") :
  cannot open file 'sample//25.csv': No such file or directory

Comment: Strange observation: The slashes used in the original code at the beginning of this thread are back slashes. And, the function works fine, it even reads 25.csv and gives out the count of complete cases. The only problem with the initial code is it doesnt give the count of complete cases for each file if I specify a range, say 25:28. It only gives the sum of complete cases across the files in that range. I am trying to get a table with each row showing file ID and complete cases count.